# Set limitation for EditText height and maximum lines according to the screen size

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a notebook application and I want to limit my editText maximum lines according to the screen height. for example 40 lines in nexus-6p and 35 lines in nexus5 and etc.

So my question is how can I limit the editText lines?
I don't have any idea for this.

**UPDATE**

I want to create new note page when cursor reached the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the solution, thank everyone for the response.

My solution is:

```
int lineHeight = getLineHeight();
int height = getHeight();
int maximumLines = height / lineHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your screen size and put lines acording the height.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();

//Calculate the lines with the height proportion

edittext.setMaxLines(lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get **screen size** in pixel by writing following code.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

After that you can put the condition and then assign the EditText in following way

```
editText.setMaxLines();
```

**Your problem will be solved**

For more details of Screen size refer the link: [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: And how can i calculate max lines ?

Comment: @FarshidABZ you can store the value of **line** in any variable and can use any logic you want..

Comment: I'm working on it, I want a logic to calculate the max lines with the screen height. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create different layout files based on the screen dimensions. In those layout files you can change the maxLine parameter for the EditText.

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: No, exactly I want to set maximum lines, cause I want to create new note page when cursor reached to the last line. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your `EditText` just contains chars, use `screenSize/editText.getLineHeight()`. However, if it also contains some mark-ups(like `Spannable`), this method will be useless and there may not be a solution.